# How to keep a window in focus thats in focus

Tags: powershell

This piece of code brings a window thats out of focus into the front. Question how do I keep it there if the user does a mouse click? Is there a way to disable mouse clicks while the script is running?

```
param([string] $proc="C:\Program Files (x86)\Citrix\ICA Client\concentr.exe", [string]$adm)
cls

 Add-Type @"
  using System;
 using System.Runtime.InteropServices;
 public class WinAp {
 [DllImport("user32.dll")]
 [return: MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.Bool)]
  public static extern bool SetForegroundWindow(IntPtr hWnd);

 [DllImport("user32.dll")]
 [return: MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.Bool)]
 public static extern bool ShowWindow(IntPtr hWnd, int nCmdShow);
  }

 "@
 $p = Get-Process |where {$_.mainWindowTItle }|where {$_.Name -like "$proc"}

 if (($p -eq $null) -and ($adm -ne ""))
 {
 Start-Process "$proc" -Verb runAs
 }
 elseif (($p -eq $null) -and ($adm -eq ""))
{
Start-Process "$proc" #-Verb runAs
 }
 else
 {
$h = $p.MainWindowHandle

[void] [WinAp]::SetForegroundWindow($h)
[void] [WinAp]::ShowWindow($h,3);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

There is a simple cmdlet to do that in [PS Community Extensions](http://pscx.codeplex.com/). 
You can use it like this:

```
Set-ForegroundWindow (Get-Process PowerShell).MainWindowHandle
```

In your case,

```
Set-ForegroundWindow $p.MainWindowHandle
```

should do your job I believe.

Hope it helps.

Comment: Thanks, but that would mean I would have to copy that to all PC's across the enterprise.

Comment: To be straight forward , YES... but you can incorporate the same with reporting if you have a desktop session active.

Comment: Depending on the size you could convert the module to base64, add it to your script, and then convert it back in the start of your script, and then load it, however this is the literal definition of a Trojan, and some virus detection systems may see it the same way too and simply delete your script wherever it's running from.

Answer (score 0):

This block disables the mouse and keyboard for 20 seconds and still allows the rest of my script to continue.

```
 Start-Job -ScriptBlock { 
 $code = @"
[DllImport("user32.dll")]
public static extern bool BlockInput(bool fBlockIt);
"@

 $userInput = Add-Type -MemberDefinition $code -Name UserInput -Namespace   UserInput -PassThru

function Disable-UserInput($seconds) {
$userInput::BlockInput($true)
Start-Sleep $seconds
$userInput::BlockInput($false)
}

Disable-UserInput -seconds 20 | Out-Null  
}
```